# Stuck in safe mode in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwgsW.png)

I accidentally clicked the `Preview in safe mode` button.
Then it was fixed in safe mode and I couldn't do anything. No matter how much I click the trust project button, I can't do anything in safe mode.
How the hell am I supposed to solve this?

Android studio chipmunk.

Answer (score -1):

Trust the project by clicking on "trust the project" as shown on your screen.

Answer (score -1):

Change project structure from "Android" to "Project". Open any file and click trust project wait for until loaded.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IsGrslrdnM - video how to fix